# Spring Data - @Transactional annotation in Service class raises AopConfigException

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop, cglib

I am using Spring and Hibernate and I am successfully autowiring a **Repository** inside the contructor of a *Service* class. When i try to add `@Transactional` methods in my **Service** class i get an `AopConfigException` that it is about the generation of **CGLib** class.

---

My Configuration consists in 3 files.
An `AppInitializer` class that implements `WebApplicationInitializer` , a `WebMvcConfig` class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` and lastly a `PersistentContext` class.

**AppInitializer**

```
public class AppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    private static final String CONFIG_LOCATION = "com.project.app.config";
    private static final String MAPPING_URL = "/";

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
        WebApplicationContext context = getContext();   
        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(context));
        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet("DispatcherServlet",
                new DispatcherServlet(context));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping(MAPPING_URL);

    }

    private AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext getContext() {
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        context.setConfigLocation(CONFIG_LOCATION);
        return context;
    }
```

**WebMvcConfig**

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.project.app" })
public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {            
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("hello");
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationContextProvider applicationContextProvider() {
        return new ApplicationContextProvider();
    }
}
```

**PersistentContext**

```
@Component
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.project.app.services.repositories")
@EnableTransactionManagement
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class PersistenceContext {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    @Primary
    public DataSource dataSource() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        DataSource ds = new DataSource();
        ds.setUrl(env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_URL));
        ds.setUsername(env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_USERNAME));
        ds.setPassword(env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_PASSWORD));
        ds.setDriverClassName(env.getProperty(SystemSettings.DS_DRIVER));    
        return ds;
    }

    @Bean
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory(DataSource dataSource) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.project.app.services.entities");
        // .. Set Properties..  
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);    
        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

    @Bean
    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

}
```

---

The Repository *INTERFACE* extends `CrudRepository`

**StopRepository**

```
@Repository
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "stop", path = "stop")
public interface StopRepository extends CrudRepository<StopJPA, Long> {   
    @Override
    StopJPA save(StopJPA persisted);    
}
```

The Entity class.

**StopJPA**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "stop")
public class StopJPA implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "stop_description")
    private String stopDescription;

    @Column(name = "id_stop", nullable = false)
    private String idStop;

    public StopJPA() {
    }

    public StopJPA(String stopDescription, String idStop) {
        this.stopDescription = stopDescription;
        this.idStop = idStop;
    }

    // .. Getters & Setters ..

}
```

And the Service class implementation:

**StopService**

```
@Service
final class RepoStopService {
    private StopRepository stopRepository;

    @Autowired
    RepoStopService(StopRepository stopRepository) {
        this.stopRepository = stopRepository;
    }

    @Transactional
    public StopDTO create(StopDTO newEntry) {
        StopJPA created = new StopJPA(newEntry.getStopDescription(), newEntry.getIdStop());
        created = stopRepository.save(created);
        return EntitiesConverter.mapEntityIntoDTO(created);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately when i try to run it on server i get this exception:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'repoStopService' defined in file [C:..\RepoStopService.class]: Initialization of bean failed;
>   Caused by: org.springframework.aop.framework.**AopConfigException**:**Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class ..RepoStopService]**: Common causes of this problem include using a final class or a non-visible class; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot subclass final class class ..RepoStopService

I understand that Spring uses either JDK proxy or CGLib. The default behavior if we autowire an interface (here its the repository) is to have a JDK proxy? 
what need to be changed in order to make it work?

Comment: Did you see the Spring forum about this problem? http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web/social/103454-could-not-generate-cglib-subclass

Comment: Have you actually read the exception? It is about your service it isn't complaining about the repositories.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The exception message is quite clear

```
AopConfigException:Could not generate CGLIB subclass of class [class ..RepoStopService
```

First of all it is complaining about the fact that it cannot create a proxy for your service it doesn't mention your repositories at all. Your service is a class without an interface and it is also `final`.

The `@Transactional` is on a method in your service. Spring needs to create a proxy for your service to be able to start and commit the transaction at that point. As your service isn't implementing an interface it tries to create a class based proxy, however it cannot because your class is marked `final`.

To fix, remove the `final` or create an interface to be able to use JDK Dynamic proxies instead of Cglib based class proxies.

**Note:** Depending on the version of Spring used, it will still fail when removing the `final` keyword as on earlier versions it is also required to have a no-arg default constructor and you only have a single argument constructor.

Comment: Good answer @M. Denium

Comment: Thanks very much for the explanation. Simple and clear. I am too many hours on this project, and i didnt notice that the class was Final (which was actually the problem).  Thanks again :)